JHipster JDL with many-to-many relationship on more than 2 related entities
I have a requirement where I need a single many-to-many relationship table with 3 related entities i.e. Course - Person - Role
Explanation of relationship:
In a Course there might be multiple people involved with different Roles (teacher/student/other).
Also a Person might be involved in more than a single Course at a time with different Roles.
So each combination of Course - Person - Role would be unique and have to definitely be related with only many-to-many relationship.
(PS: Please note that the entities I've mentioned are only for exemplary purpose and not to be considered with their literal relationship.)
Requirement:
I already created 3 entities (Course, Person, Role) in my JDL file. Now, I need to link them with many-to-many relationship inside a single table (suppose named as Course_Person_Role).
I earlier worked linking 2 entities with the many-to-many relationship, but not sure how to link >2 entities.
Please guide.
